# How does layout_width/height work together with min/max width/height

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to understand who "wins" when setting the following attributes in xml:
1. layout_width vs minWidth/maxWidth
2. layout_height vs minHeight/maxHeight

For example, the following code:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/pb_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/semi_transparent_black_for_pb_loader"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to understand what will be the **ProgressBar** size. in addition i found the value of *style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"*. attached here:

```
 <style name="Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="indeterminateOnly">true</item>
    <item name="indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_medium_white</item>
    <item name="indeterminateBehavior">repeat</item>
    <item name="indeterminateDuration">3500</item>
    <item name="minWidth">48dip</item>
    <item name="maxWidth">48dip</item>
    <item name="minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="maxHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="mirrorForRtl">false</item>
</style>
```

now, can someone tell me why when using **wrap_content** it's seems that the size is determined according to **minWidth**, **maxWidth**, **minHeight**,**maxHeight**, whereas when setting **layout_width** and **layout_height** of the **ProgressBar** to "0dp", then it's **"overcome"** over the min/max and takes **a lot of place from the screen**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set layout_width and layout_height to "0dp" it will respect the constraints that are defined. In your case:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

So it will take the whole space of the parent layout. This is similar as "match_parent".

Where with "wrap_content" it will have the default size in this case 48dp as you found in the style definition.